# Change any copied text and/or image to my own text when copied

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say, that I'd want to replace any copied text (or any other content) from my site with my own text, for example *Copyright*. If I'd paste it (outside the browser), the pasted content would be *Copyright*. Could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

No. (And some extra text to allow Stack Overflow to accept the answer.)

Actually, it would be possible but only with a lot of extra work. You could, for example, convert all your HTML to images.

There's also additional information on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: What do you mean by *convert all your HTML to image*?